# Does acceptance of communication with identifying characteristics originating from a disputed territory imply recognition of that territory?

Tags: international, claims, jurisprudence, attribution, communications-law

To give an example:

One of the more well known currently disputed territories is Crimea. As telecommunication services, and users of such, do continue to operate from that territory under the aegis of a Russian persona, (like a Crimean based website using a .ru domain or personal and business phones in Crimea using a Russian country code), does acceptance of such communication imply recognizing the territory as part of Russia?

To me it seems a bit tricky because in the ordinary sense the answer would be of course. It would be silly to accept a phone call, carry on a conversation, then refuse to accept the first few digits of the phone number.

If this norm holds then the communication operators and their receivers are recognizing identifying claims. However, in this case that would mean accepting that Crimea is no longer part of Ukraine. And governments are receivers of communication too.

(There does not seem to exist technical means to block the propogation of such communication. And it also may not even be possible, for internet companies specifically, to refuse recognition of any technically valid domain without jeopardizing their interconnections.)

Comment: Taiwan has a domain, phone prefix, a government, an Olympic Committee, an army, a navy, an air force, and hundreds of other things, yet is not recognized by anybody, even though it is treated the same as almost any other recognized country. OTOH, North Korea is recognized by everybody, but treated very different from almost any other country. Recognition really does not mean much other than a political gesture to boost national pride.

Comment: Note that ICANN, IANA, and the IETF make it *very clear* that the fact that a ccTLD exists makes no statement about the legitimacy of that country. In fact, they punt the decision to the UN statistics bureau. The UN statistics bureau, in turn, also makes it very clear that the fact that a certain region gets a two-letter code assigned only means that this particular region is interesting enough for statistical purposes to warrant a separate code … no more, no less.

Comment: "then refuse to accept the first few digits of the phone number" - accepting the fact that you are being called from a certain number (i.e. accepting reality as it is), and also calling or receiving calls from such numbers, has very little to do with agreeing with the reasons people chose to make the number what it is.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the detail. “ this particular region is interesting enough for statistical purposes to warrant a separate code” does seem to imply recognition of something though, if we apply normal logic.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, Taiwan is an unusual case: almost everyone maintains the pretense that Taiwan is part of a unified China, and the dispute is merely a question of whether the legitimate government is the one in Beijing, or the one in Taipei.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag  according to the Wikipedia article "only 14 UN member states and the Holy See maintain official diplomatic relations with the Republic of China" which is not quoit the same as "is not recognized by anybody" although it is a very small number.

Comment: @DavidSiegel more can be said.  Taiwan was the original member of the 5 permanent members of the UN security council.  Ronald Reagan publicly condemned it as a "betrayal" by the UN to remove Taiwan in favor of China (while he was still a governor of California.

Comment: DNS resolving internet domain names into IP addresses is not an official government business.  It's done by private interests.  Its use signifies absolutely nothing.  [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.su), 100,000 '.su' domains still exist.  This is despite the fact that the Soviet Union does not, so to speak, recognize Soviet Union.  USSR was officially dissolved by a proclamation of the Supreme Soviet on December 26th, 1991.  IF YOU WANT A MORE SERIOUS ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION, you may want to ask it about physical mail and packages addressed to/from places in Crimea.

Comment: @grovkin As far as I’m aware lettermail is usually considered to be communication.

Comment: I think you might be using the word "communication" as a legal term of some sort.  It isn't though, at least not without some qualifier attached to it.  This maybe causing some confusion as to what it is that you are asking.  It may also be causing some confusion about what you say in comments.  I don't mean this as criticism.  But it would probably reduce the confusion if you clarified what legal concept you have in mind (if you are using "communication" as a legal term).

Comment: Any examples involving the Internet will fall flat because it does not have a concept of national gateways. Traffic to websites in the .ru domain is not routed to Russia like a letter in the mail would be. It is routed to wherever the private party which registered the domain chooses. Lots of sites in .ru have their servers with cloud providers in other countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question conflates "recognizing the *existence* of a territory/organization/state" and "recognizing the *geographical boundaries* of a territory/organization/state."

Your example is "a Crimean based website using a .ru domain." I don't see any difference between "a Crimean based website using a .ru domain" and, say, "a U.S.-based website using an [.io domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.io)" (like, e.g., my blog hosted on github.io). I *live* in the U.S. and *maintain* a website in the .io domain; that doesn't even remotely suggest that the U.S. is *physically* part of the British Indian Ocean Territory.

You also seem to be worried about some sort of [magic-words trap](https://www.albertalawreview.com/index.php/ALR/article/view/2485) where someone could say "Aha, you visited [www.unitedstates.io](http://www.unitedstates.io), therefore you are legally bound to recognize that the United States is part of the Indian Ocean Territory!"

Likewise, if certain people located physically in Crimea happen to run websites under .ru, that doesn't mean that Crimea is *physically* part of Russia; and if you happen to visit [www.crimea.ru](http://www.crimea.ru), that doesn't imply any kind of legal agreement that Crimea is (or is not) part of Russia.

---

Getting back to the conflation... There is definitely more of an argument to be made that the existence of the .ru TLD implies that someone, somewhere, recognizes the existence of Russia. However, as Jörg W Mittag pointed out in the comments, domain-name TLDs are more or less based on the two-letter abbreviations maintained by the U.N.'s Statistics Division, and the U.N.'s Statistics Division [very clearly states](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/):

> The designations employed and the presentation of material at this site **do not imply the expression of any opinion whatsoever** on the part of the Secretariat of the United Nations concerning the legal status of any country, territory, city or area or of its authorities, **or concerning the delimitation of its frontiers or boundaries.**

---

This doesn't directly address your concerns about phone-number country codes, but I can't imagine any reason for the logic and rationales re: phone numbers to "work" any differently from the logic and rationales expressed above re: TLDs.

---

UPDATE: @MichaelZ, from your comments below, I surmise that you don't really get how DNS works. When you direct your browser to (let's say) [www.crimea.ru](http://www.crimea.ru), all that happens is that your computer looks up that name in a big distributed "phone book," starting at the top ("at the root") and then descending: you ask the root "What's the IP address of [www.crimea.ru?"](http://www.crimea.ru?%22) and the root says "I don't know, but on the subject of .ru domains, I trust a.dns.ripn.net, whose IP address is 193.232.128.6." So then your computer asks 193.232.128.6 "What's the IP address of [www.crimea.ru?"](http://www.crimea.ru?%22) and 193.232.128.6 says "I don't know, but on the subject of .crimea.ru domains, I trust ns1.ht-systems.ru, whose IP address is 78.110.50.60." So then your computer asks 78.110.50.60 "What's the IP address of [www.crimea.ru?"](http://www.crimea.ru?%22) and 78.110.50.60 says "Oh, that's 78.110.50.130." So then your computer sends an HTTP GET request (or whatever you're interested in doing) to 78.110.50.130. If it's HTTP or HTTPS, it'll also send some header data that basically says "Hello 78.110.50.130! A little bird told me you were www.crimea.ru; is that right?"

There's a lower level, "IP" (Internet Protocol), that handles the routing of packets to these various IP addresses. In a sense, the Internet Protocol "recognizes" the relationship between certain IP blocks and certain geographical regions of the Earth. However, it does not recognize *political* boundaries; there's no concept of an IP address saying "I am Russian" in the same way that a domain name could say "I am Russian (.ru)." (*And, again, a domain name can "say" it's Russian only in the same sense that it can "say" it's the Indian Ocean; that doesn't necessarily have any bearing on geographical reality.*)

Anyway, does this help clarify why none of this technology stuff has any bearing on geographical or political boundaries?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This seems to imply that TLDs are abitrary, yet many TLDs do require some form of legal verification relating to citizenship, residency, etc., for registration. For example to operate a .ca domain name requires proof that the registrant is physically within Canada or is a Canadian citizen, as far as I understand it. The obvious justification of .ca belonging to Canada, and for many other cases, wouldn’t work if TLDs aren’t supposed to rely on that.

Comment: @MichaelZ: Suppose that Canada decided to let Americans buy .ca domains. Canada has an absolute and unilateral right to do that; the .ca TLD is entirely under their legal control, and many other countries do allow foreigners to purchase such domains in their respective ccTLDs (indeed, domain registration fees are said to constitute 10% of the GDP of Tuvalu!). But it would not, in any sense, constitute a claim of sovereignty over America, much less an *exercise* of such purported sovereignty.

Comment: @Kevin I was thinking of it from the opposite direction. How could any country’s government claim complete control, and make binding decisions, over any given TLD? If they don’t necessarily belong to any given territory or its representatives...

Comment: @MichaelZ: Well, that's a different question from the one you asked. Nobody seriously denies that Russia *as a whole* exists, and IANA (the non-profit which establishes ccTLDs in the first place) doesn't care about the extent of Russia's territory, only about who actually gets to administer .ru. In other words, IANA doesn't care who owns Crimea; they care about who owns Russia as a whole, regardless of what its precise boundaries look like. Obviously this is harder with a territory like Taiwan, where there's disagreement over whether a "country" even exists, but Crimea is not like that.

Comment: @Kevin I am unsure as to how global network peering actually works so I’m not quit sure what you mean. Surely when Russian internet companies set up shop in Crimea they had to make some sort of agreement with their global peers and regulatory bodies... Otherwise why would everyone cease to direct Crimea network traffic through the Ukranian companies and network? Or have they?

Comment: @MichaelZ: You're conflating DNS with BGP; they are technically very different things, delegated at different levels of authority, and operating on different primitives. DNS turns a name like "example.com" into an IP address. BGP decides where traffic should go in order to get to its destination (which is already an IP address). DNS is centralized through a hierarchy of registries; BGP is decentralized and each autonomous system only talks to its neighbors (peers). A DNS registry, for ccTLDs, is controlled or delegated by its government; a BGP AS merely has to follow local law.

Comment: @Kevin So BGP does not have a central regulatory body? That is the decision for where any given packet goes is ultimately based on group consensus?

Comment: @MichaelZ: Almost. You do have to convince an RIR to issue you an [ASN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)), or else you can't even get started with playing the BGP game. That's usually just a matter of controlling a big network, however. And if you start making outlandish claims (like "hey everybody, I have the best route for every IP address on the entire internet!"), then your peers will probably disbelieve you. But they screw this up with [surprising regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP_hijacking).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the info. It seems in this case at least one RIR (RIPE NCC) would still have had to recognize the change. Otherwise, the Ukranian controlled ASNs would continue to demand everyone to route Crimea traffic through them, and most would keep on trying. I’m not sure if this was ever disputed but it seems likely that the Russian companies would try and the relevant RIR would have made a final decision.

Comment: @MichaelZ That is not how BGP works. The whole purpose of BGP is to allow the owner of an IP address to change inbound routing all by itself. If an ISP in Crimea has a peer in Kiev and the cable is cut, then the BGP messages keeping the route through Kiev alive will not get through and in a few minutes the route will expire from the routing tables of the whole Internet. If the ISP in Crimea has a second cable to a router in Sochi, all it has to do is send BGP announcements down that cable and the whole Internet will reroute automatically. No humans involved, no political statements made.

Comment: @David42 Ah I see, so once an ASN has been issued then whoever controls it is pretty much free to do as they wish. The Wiki page nor the RIR sites were clear about that. Do the RIRs at least have the ability to revoke ASNs?

Comment: @MichaelZ The ASN is simply an organization ID number which senders voluntarily put on their BGP messages. It does not grant access to send BGP. You get that access when your peers agree to  act on BGP messages you send them. If you start offering to route packets to the IP address block of an ISP in Crimea and don't do it, technicians at your peers will tell their routers to ignore your BGP messages. They would be defending the rights of the company which owns the IP block to have it routed as they see fit. It will not be a political statement.

Comment: @MichaelZ Actually I overstated that. The technicians won't necessarily be defending anyone's rights. They will be trying to close a trouble ticket from a customer who can't reach a website. Maybe they will notice that it is hosted in Crimea, maybe not. But they will see two routes advertised. One works. The other doesn't. They will block the bad one and forget about it. But you are talking about publishing possibly hundreds of bogus routes. The technicians at your peers are not going to like having to block them one at a time and may hit you with a blanket ban.

Comment: @MichaelZ BPB **doesn't care**, and barely knows, about `.ru`, it cares about 123.222.011.143 style IP addresses (or IPv6).  DNS convert `foo.ru` to such an IP address (it is a phone book), and can generate literally any IP address for `foo.ru` (including, say, one used by google.com).  Once it is an IP address, the packet gets routed using BGB, which is a peer-to-peer protocol at the "large network" level of the internet, and usually cares not and knows not what country is what network or IP address.

Comment: There is a system whereby the computer you are talking to at a specific IP address owns the domain you think you are talking to -- various https and https type protocols do this.  So if BGB routes `foo.ru`'s IP through lies to a different computer address, you connect and find out that the other computer is not the same as the `foo.ru`'s owner, and your browser says "this connection is insecure" or the like message (and/or silently drops the packet as junk).  The outgoing stuff is also encrypted so only the owner of `foo.ru` can read it.

Comment: @David42 Thanks for the detailed explanation. From what it sounds like the worldwide collective group of organizations that utilize BGP, and have been granted an ASN, police each other on a group consensus basis. Is that about right?

Comment: @MichaelZ You're welcome. In answer to your last question, almost everything on the Internet works by group consensus. The few bureaucratic organizations I can think of perform a very limited role. Mainly they just hand out ID numbers and maintain lists of assigned names. Politicians became aware of the Internet far too late to have much influence on design and practices. As a result, Internet traffic crosses international borders whenever it is convenient to do so. Politicians are only starting to worry about this.

Answer (score 8):

### No

Recognition of territorial claims is the sole province of the diplomatic branches of national government, and of heads  of state. In the US it is the State Department, and ultimately the President. The actions of telephone operators and  people engaging in other forms of communication cannot and do not bind the decisions of the President, or of other heads of state.

Besides, there may be cases in which a telephone country code or a web domain may not match the actual, undisputed legal status of a territory. Accepting a phone call does not affect a country's legal status.

For decades the US did not recognize the communist regime in China. Legally, it considered that the  Republic of China (aka Taiwan) was the only valid government, and the acceptance of telephone calls did not change that.

Comment: By your answer they officially wouldn’t, but in practice how would that be addressed in the courts and regulation? Would the existence of such websites, phones, etc., or their identifying characteristics be denied? (I am not sure if there is a technical means to block the propogation of such communication unless every other country were to block outbound traffic from Russia.)

Comment: @MichaelZ  The existence of such websites and telephone numbers would not be denied, but it would not be considered evidence of the legal status of such territories. Only the official recognition or no recognition by tteh national officials and ultimately by the President (in the US) would be officially considered; the phone code or web code simply is not considered to define the legal nationality.

Comment: Hmmm.. so a de jure no, but a de facto yes?

Comment: @MichaelZ It could be thought of that way, but even on a *de facto* basis telephone codes would not be determative or even highly persuasive. A military occupation, or the control of civil administration in practice is much more to the point. Often, of course, it will match the phone codes.

Answer (score 7):

### No

As a matter of international law, each country is free to accept or reject the territorial claims (and even the existence) of every other country.

Many nations do not recognize Russia’s claims over Crimea - it doesn’t change the facts on the ground. Similarly, many countries recognize China’s claims over Formosa (Taiwan), or the Palestinian claims of statehood - that also doesn’t change the facts.

Neither does accepting mail.